# Google Maps Javascript API, get neighborhood name

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geolocation

I need to dynamically create neighborhood records as users search for their neighborhoods. [This example here](https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/maps/documentation/utils/geocoder) using the Google Maps API returns the perfect results.

For example, when I search Magrath Height, I can see the it on the autocomplete, and on results (neighborhood: Magrath Heights). However, I don't get the same in my example:

**index.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Google Location Search Example</title>

<!-- CSS only -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-F3w7mX95PdgyTmZZMECAngseQB83DfGTowi0iMjiWaeVhAn4FJkqJByhZMI3AhiU" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <!-- JavaScript Bundle with Popper -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-/bQdsTh/da6pkI1MST/rWKFNjaCP5gBSY4sEBT38Q/9RBh9AH40zEOg7Hlq2THRZ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="./index.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <form id="address-form" action="" method="get" autocomplete="off">
                <div class="mb-3">
                    <label for="exampleInputEmail1" class="form-label">Your location</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp">
                    <div id="emailHelp" class="form-text">Type your community, or location name</div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="container" id="pnlresults">
            Start typing to see the location info.
        </div>

<script async
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=XYZ&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete">
</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**index.js**

```
let autocomplete;
let searchField;
let results;

function initAutocomplete(){
    searchField = document.querySelector("#exampleInputEmail1");
    results = document.querySelector("#pnlresults");

    autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
        searchField,
        {
            componentRestrictions: { country: ["ca","in","ae"] },
            fields: ['address_components'],
            types:['address'],
        }
    );
    
    searchField.focus();
    autocomplete.addListener('place_changed',onPlaceChangedNeighborhood);
}

function onPlaceChangedNeighborhood(){
    const place = autocomplete.getPlace();

    let neighborhood = "";
    let province = "";
    let country = "";

    for (const component of place.address_components) {
        const componentType = component.types[0];

        switch (componentType) {
            case "administrative_area_level_1": {
                province =component.long_name;
                break;
            }
            case "sublocality_level_1":{
                neighborhood = component.short_name
                break;
            }
            case "country":
            {
                country = component.long_name
                break;
            }
        }
    }  
    
    results.innerHTML = "Neighborhood: " + neighborhood + "<br/>Province/state: " + province + "<br/>Country = " + country;
}
```

Do you know why I am not seeing Magrath Heights in search, and also the neighborhood in the results? I have tried a few other componentTypes such as 'locality'.

Appreciate any response.

Comment: Use the appropriate [types](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/supported_types#table3) parameter in your autocomplete options.

Comment: Unfortunately, when I change to any other type, I do not see any results. It seems to not working except for the "address" on the type field.

Comment: `types: ['geocode']` works fine for me with the example you provided, but not with `address_components` field.

Comment: Oh okay, thanks. Yeah, it works too

Comment: You should adapt your answer then as it is not a solution, rather a work around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I figured it out. If anyone else has this issue, this is what you do.

I changed my initAutocomplete() from this;

```
function initAutocomplete(){
    searchField = document.querySelector("#exampleInputEmail1");
    results = document.querySelector("#pnlresults");

    autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
        searchField,
        {
            componentRestrictions: { country: ["ca","in","ae"] },
            fields: ['address_components','name','geometry'],
            types:['address'],
        }
    );
    
    searchField.focus();
    autocomplete.addListener('place_changed',onPlaceChangedNeighborhood);
}
```

to this (removed all the parameters except for the search field in new google.maps.places.Autocomplete):

```
function initAutocomplete(){
    searchField = document.querySelector("#exampleInputEmail1");
    results = document.querySelector("#pnlresults");

    autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
        searchField
    );
    
    searchField.focus();
    autocomplete.addListener('place_changed',onPlaceChangedNeighborhood);
}
```

I am not sure about the drawbacks (more general results, etc.)